# not able to find IFSC code from RozarPay IFSC-Api

Tags: android, api, razorpay

This RazaorPay Api (https://github.com/razorpay/ifsc-api) provide All banks details only if we provide IFSC code.

- I need **Api** that provide All Banks list, State list, District list.

**Not able to get IFSC code from this Api in this type**= (`Bank > State > District > Branch >then their IFSC`)